# Getting local PC IP ( for use in cron script )

Tags: php, cron

I created a script to search for, copy, compress and send files from a Cliet/Local PC to a Master PC.

The files need to be identified on the master PC. the format is

```
`UUID.IP.crc.gz`
```

So the PC running the script (Local), I need that PC's IP address.

I've tried using `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`, but none of those where defined.

`Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_ADDR in C:\wamp\www\postEnginInstruction\properties.php on line 9`
and the same for `"REMOTE_ADDR"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use php with a CRON, there is no HTTP request nor server, you just use it as a script language. So you can't access $_SERVER value.

You have to use then a command like ipconfig (or ifconfig on linux) with the exec command in PHP.

Edit : look here also for easier solutions : [How do I find my server's IP address in PHP(CLI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814611/how-do-i-find-my-servers-ip-address-in-phpcli)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do to 'create' an HTTP request is schedule a `curl`-command to activate your PHP script:

```
curl http://your.server/path/to/your/scheduledScript.php
```

There is however one downside: your scheduled script would also be invokable from the outside. This is something you should manage. (Either through `.htaccess` Allow/Deny directives, or some form of generating and providing one-time tokens from CRON).

(One last sidenote: make sure you use the DNS name of your server, if you use localhost, the address is probably going to be `127.0.01`, which is not very helpful) ;)